# SetInterval for hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input field here, when I hover on input field asterisk adds, when I lose hover input text is clean. How with setInterval(maybe) I can add additional asterisk in input field every second when it's hovered?

```
$('body').append("<input type='text' />");

  $('input').hover(function() {
     $(this).val('*' + $(this).val());
  })
$('input').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).val('');
})
```

Comment: An asterisk should be appended to the input every second as long as the mouse still hovers it?

Comment: @haim770 Yeah I suppose

Comment: Yes, thats right!

Comment: The problem you have here is a delegation one though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an interval and store it in `$.data` to clear it on mouseeleave

```js
var input = $('<input />', {
  type : 'text',
  on   : {
    mouseenter : function() {
      var self = this;
      
      $(this).val('*').data('interval', setInterval(function() {
        self.value += '*';
      },1000));
    },
    mouseleave : function() {
      clearInterval( $(this).data('interval') );
      this.value = "";
    }
  }
});

$('body').append(input);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/28Lsjq7n/1/)

Comment: Nice use of `data` attribute, instead of setting a global flag. I didn't think of it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
$(this).val('*' + $(this).val());
```

With

```
setInterval(function(){ $("#input").val($("#input").val() + "*") }, 1000);
```

That should do the trick

Comment: `$(this)` is invalid, since `this` is refering to the anonymous function. `$('input').hover(function() {
     var elm = $(this);
setInterval(function(){ elm.val(elm.val() + "*") }, 1000);
  });`

Comment: This is also right answer but '#input' don't have unique id in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to also use `clearInterval` to prevent the function to be executed when the mouse leaves the input.

You should store the ID that `setInterval` returns. When mouse leaves (or mouse hovers again), you can clear the previous interval id.

```
  $('body').append("<input type='text' />");
  var id = null;
  $('input').hover(function() {
    var element = this;
    clearInterval(id)
    id = setInterval(function () {
     $(element).val('*' + $(element).val()); 
    }, 1000)

  })
  $('input').mouseleave(function() {
    clearInterval(id)
    console.log(id);
    $(this).val('');
  })
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/wKiw8B8oihQBZU5gTcdk?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You don't actualy need for `mouseleave` because in `hover` you can pass both actions:
[**`.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`**](https://api.jquery.com/hover/). (Behind the scene of `handlerOut` is `mouseleave`)

Add `this` (input) to the interval on hover

```
var interval = null;
$('input').hover(function() { 
  interval = setInterval(function(el){
    $(el).val($(el).val() + "*");
  }, 1000, this);
}, function(){
  clearInterval(interval);
  $(this).val('');
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/d7gsgr1b/)